# Cannot connect to ec2 instance after rubber automatic reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

enter code hereI I'm trying to deploy to ec2 a rails 3 app using rubber for my first time. During the run of the command cap rubber:create_staging the instance was asked to do a reboot and then it won't accept a connection. This is how it looks:

```
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Setting up grub2-common (1.99-21ubuntu3.1) ...
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Setting up grub-pc-bin (1.99-21ubuntu3.1) ...
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Setting up grub-pc (1.99-21ubuntu3.1) ...
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Generating grub.cfg ...
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-virtual
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-virtual
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-virtual
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-virtual
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn:
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] .
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] done
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Processing triggers for resolvconf ...
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink, not doing anything.
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-virtual
    command finished in 131854ms
  * executing "echo $(ls /var/run/reboot-required 2> /dev/null)"
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
    [production.foo.com] executing command
    command finished in 460ms
  * executing "echo $(ls /mnt/your_app_name-production 2> /dev/null)"
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
    [production.foo.com] executing command
    command finished in 473ms
 ** Updates require a reboot on hosts ["production.foo.com"]
 ** Rebooting ...
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' reboot"
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
    [production.foo.com] executing command
    command finished in 479ms
  * executing `rubber:_direct_connection_production.foo.com_887'
  * executing "echo"
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
 ** Failed to connect to production.foo.com, retrying
```

The problem is that by running rubber:create or any other rubber command, after the instance is created and initialized, after the /etc/hosts file is written, then I receive a "connection failed" error and everything stops there.

If I do an ssh to the address written in the hosts file, then I am able to connect perfectly to the instance so I don't understand where the problem lies…

Answer (score 0):

make sure from the EBS volume /dev/xvda1 is already attached to the ex2 instance.

Goto EC2 -> Volumes and take a look to the EBS volume that you have. id you see that volume is in the available state try to attach it the ec2 instance and reboot the instance.